# How can I configure a multi lingual (language) website?

Tags: magento2, localisation, language

I have created following store structure;

Website: xxx.de
Store: Germany
Store View: German

Website: xxx.nl
Store: Netherlands
Store View: Dutch

Website: xxx.fr
Store: France
Store View: French

I want to use all languages on other websites too like French and German on xxx.nl with Dutch language. I don't want to create same languages under stores it's to much work for translate and I do use "Add Store Code to URLs " option I will keep it too for all websites.

Comment: Hi, i noticed you created additional stores, not just Store Views. Do your other stores use different catalogs or have other major differences? If everything is the same and you just want to use different languages you just do store views. Are you doing different currencies?

Comment: I use same catalogs, but as i mentioned i use different domains for stores.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement ,You need to develop it by custom code or need to use extension for it or you need to create same languages under stores to achieve it.

As you said that you don't want to create same languages under stores as it's to much work so i can give you one solution for that.

You can use this language translator extension (https://marketplace.magento.com/zealousweb-module-gtranslator.html). Please check it out. Its a google translator.

You already have french and German's different website. So for example ,you are using dutch language with xxx.nl website so you can use "french" and "german" language with google translator extension in xxx.nl website.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, but it's not a good idea. It's to bad for SEO and it gives not confidence for visitors. https://www.accelingo.com/why-you-should-not-use-google-translate/